# Go: How can I create an instance of type schema.ResourceData with values for unit testing?

Tags: go, testing, terraform

I want to write a unit test for a method similar to this:

```golang
package bingo

import "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema"

func doStuff(d *schema.ResourceData) error {
    foo := d.Get("foo").(string)
    // ... operations using d
    return nil
}
```

Is there a way to create an instance of type `schema.ResourceData` with values in it?

I tried creating a "blank" instance of `ResourceData` and populate it via `.Set(...)`. But it doesn't work, since no schema is present:

```golang
package bingo

import "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema"

func TestDoStuff(t *testing.T) {
    d := schema.ResourceData{}
    err := d.Set("foo", "bar")
    if err != nil {
      t.Errorf("failed to set value: %s", err)
      // > failed to set value: Invalid address to set: []string{"foo"}
    }

    // test doStuff()
}
```

Comment: Try https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema#TestResourceDataRaw

Comment: Worked for me like a charm! Thanks @mkopriva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`schema.TestResourceDataRaw` does exactly that:

```golang
package bingo

import "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema"

var testSchema = map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "foo": {Type: schema.TypeString}
}

func TestDoStuff(t *testing.T) {
    d := schema.TestResourceDataRaw(t, testSchema, map[string]interface{
        "foo": "bar",
    })
    err := doStuff(d)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

[Link to the documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema#TestResourceDataRaw)

Thanks to @mkopriva for pointing out the builtin helper method.